# jquery animate with percenteges

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-animate

Is there any way i can animate a div using percentages with jquery?

I've tried these:

```
$('.box1').animate({width:($(".wrapper").width()*.100)},"fast");})
$('.box1').animate({width:'100%'},"fast");})
$('.box1').animate({width:100%;})
```

none of the above work...

any ideas?

UPDATE

```
var p_e_h= 1.0;
var p_e_w= 1.0;
 $('.box1').animate({width:($(".wrapper").width()* p_e_w)},"fast");
       $('.box1').animate({height:($(".wrapper").height()* p_e_h)},"fast");
```

width works, but height does not. Unless i click the button again.

Comment: `width: 100%;` would be treated as trying to take the modulo of 100 using a semicolon as the divisor - a syntax error.

Comment: `*.100` is not really 100%.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
var fiftyPrct = 0.5, //50%
    hundredPrct = 1; //100%

$('.box1').animate({ width: ($('.wrapper').width() * fiftyPrct) }, 'fast');
$('.box2').animate({ width: ($('.wrapper').width() * hundredPrct) }, 'fast');
```

Should work fine.

**Update**

Since you are doing 2 different `.animate` calls, the animations are queued and executed sequentially. Just do them with the same animation call:

```
var p_e_h= 1.0;
var p_e_w= 1.0;

$('.box1').animate({
    width: ($(".wrapper").width() * p_e_w),
    height:($(".wrapper").height() * p_e_h)
},"fast");
```

Example of it working: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ktCE6/)

Comment: hey thanks for that. it works but only with width. I have it assigned to a button. when i click the button, the width expands, but the height does not until i click the button again. could you check my update please? thanks

Comment: hmmm. That still does the same thing. shall i post all the code?

Comment: You may need to clear your browser cache because it works fine: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ktCE6/)

Comment: Ahh, solved it. It was some other code I had in there. cheers guys.