# jQuery percentage width has up tick when animating down.

Tags: jquery

Does anyone know why jQuery has an uptick in the width percentage when using animate to scale down the width of an image. This only seems to happen when you are scaling down a div with a percentage based width that is within a div that is also using a percentage based width. See [this](http://jsfiddle.net/buz9L/) example in it you can see that the square to the right drops down for a split second in the up tick. If you try ordering the animate changes on completion handlers there are similar results due to the uptick. The example is based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8299608/jquery-animate-with-percenteges) other SO issue but is unanswered for my use case. I'm guessing it has something to do with 3rds and floats in ranging limits with percentages in jQuery, but maybe there is a simple solution out there. Thanks in advance for any help.

```
Check JSFiddle Link
```

Comment: If you resize that frame, it stops happening....hmmm

Comment: Also, you have #activity twice in the first toggle

Comment: Yes it is a little random I noticed that. I did the JSFiddle in like 30 seconds, but you get the point. The only way I caught it was when I was inspecting the elements, and I watch the percentage go up about a percentage. The work around is to drop the css width by a percentage and a half without animation then do the rest of the animation. But that doesn't answer why its happening and how to fix it.

Comment: Yeah, thats kind of annoying... I don't even know where to begin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It does look like the totals for the left two columns might at one point be > 75%, which would push the last div to a new row. 
You could declare a 'linear' animation. This seemed to work a little better for me. Maybe it does less/cleaner width calculations.

Comment: I agree linear does work a little better, but no much better. Still blips down when resizing the window. It actually doesn't do it at larger resolutions. Which I'm guessing is part of the way is calc'ing the floating number math. I appreciate the help, but I don't think its a perfect solution.